# int-sftp outbound-gateway command-options is being ignored

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying to get a list of filenames from a remote directory and all its subdirectories using Spring Integration 4.1.5. Since I can only use SFTP to connect to the remote server, I need to use an `int-sftp:outbound-gateway`. Seems like it would be pretty straightforward:

```
<int-sftp:outbound-gateway id="remoteSftpLS"
        session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        request-channel="triggerChannel"
        command="ls"
        command-options="-1 -R"
        remote-file-separator="/"
        expression="payload"
        charset="UTF-8"
        filter="fileFilter"
        reply-channel="lsResultChannel" />
```

However, it seems like anything I put into command-options is ignored:

- Regardless of whether I use -R or not, I only get entries from the
  top-level directory.
- Regardless of whether I use -1 or not, I only get `FileInfo` objects, not filename strings.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not make sense. Just have tested it locally. The result is like:

```
payload = {ArrayList@3873}  size = 3
 0 = "sftpSource1.txt"
 1 = "sftpSource2.txt"
 2 = "subSftpSource/subSftpSource1.txt"
```

`SftpServerOutboundTests.testInt3172LocalDirectoryExpressionMGETRecursive` with the `sftpSource` as a remote directory and:

```
 <int-sftp:outbound-gateway session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
                          request-channel="inboundMGetRecursive"
                          command="ls"
                          expression="payload"
                          command-options="-1 -R"
                          reply-channel="output"/>
```

as a config.

Maybe your `filter` is guilty ?

```
protected final List<F> filterFiles(F[] files) {
    return (this.filter != null) ? this.filter.filterFiles(files) : Arrays.asList(files);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to be the filter. I implemented a simplistic, logging-only filter and it returns the same values as above (the contents of the target directory, not any subdirectories).  I'm still investigating; I am beginning to wonder if my Spring Integration version is too far out of date (it's 4.1.5).

Comment: No op. The code for `LS` hasn't been changed since there. Can you just debug `AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.ls()` and try to figure out what's going on?

Comment: It was in fact the filter! In a hidden way. The previous developer was sort of using the filter as an endpoint, in a way that was weird and inobvious. I replaced it with a service-activator and removed the filter, and all was well. Thanks for the pointer!